# As a marketplace, can I integrate with Stripe Connect without requiring my vendor to submit their taxpayer ID?

Tags: stripe-payments

We are trying to build a solution with Stripe Connect, and I am looking at other platform's solution with that. I found that one platform using stripe (Medium.com) require the vendor (the writers) to input taxpayer ID before they can get paid out.

Can I skip that step? (that's too much customer acquisition friction to us)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, no: https://support.stripe.com/questions/know-your-customer-kyc-requirements-for-connected-accounts

You could reach out to Support if you have further questions though: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email